# Java - Can I simplify this code using Recursion or any other methods?

Tags: java, recursion

So I have this method, roosterID is for generating an ID based on the current year and week of year, this is what I've come up with, but I don't think this is the best way to do it, I tried making the method recursive at some point.
That didn't work the way I wanted it to.
At least, the way I tried it.
Basically say there's a year that has 53 weeks, I'm calling the load method of rDAO, with the roosterID for the current week, and the 2 coming weeks.
Basically I want the roosterID to be 20141 for the week after 201353, simply using roosterID+1 would make it 201354.
I hope my explanation isn't to rubbish.

the code below works, I just think it's kind of dirty and unprofessional, and can be done a lot better, if anything changes I have to redo pretty much all the code, so i'd like some advice.

```
    public void getWeekTabs(){
    gc.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    if(gc.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) <= gc.getWeeksInWeekYear()-2){
        roosterID = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(gc.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + Integer.toString(gc.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)));
        rDAO.load(roosterID);
        rDAO.load(roosterID +1);
        rDAO.load(roosterID +2);
    }else if(gc.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) == gc.getWeeksInWeekYear()-1){
        roosterIDtemp = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(gc.get(Calendar.YEAR) +1 ) + Integer.toString(1));
        rDAO.load(roosterID);
        rDAO.load(roosterID +1);
        rDAO.load(roosterIDtemp);
    }else if(gc.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) == gc.getWeeksInWeekYear()){
        roosterIDtemp = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(gc.get(Calendar.YEAR) +1 ) + Integer.toString(1));
        rDAO.load(roosterID);
        rDAO.load(roosterIDtemp);
        rDAO.load(roosterIDtemp +1);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Something looks very wrong here.. roosterID is used in all 3 if blocks but is updated only in the first one..

Is the code correct?

Comment: Don't you want to have 201401 for the first week of 2014 instead of 20141?

Comment: Do you need to store the ID as a string? Can you store it as something else (like a date) and the present it to the user as a specifically formatted string?

Comment: This question seems better suited for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Using your code right now, I get the output for roosterID: 201345
201346
201347. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, this is weird:

```
roosterID = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(gc.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + Integer.toString(gc.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)));
```

Do this:

```
public String makeRoosterId(Calendar gc) {
    return String.format("%d%d", gc.get(Calendar.YEAR), gc.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
}
```

If you want 201401 instead of 20141, you can modify the format expression to do that.  Now, to load your three items:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); // current date
rDAO.load(makeRoosterId(c));         // Load this week
c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
rDAO.load(makeRoosterId(c));         // Load next week
c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
rDAO.load(makeRoosterId(c));         // Load the week after that
```

That should do it.

**EDIT**: See comments about issues that happen at year boundaries.

Comment: Great answer! Maybe you should replace gc.get(Calendar.YEAR) by gc.getWeekYear() to work around the first-week-of-year problem! (e.g. 1st january 2012 is in the 52th week of 2011).

Comment: Good point... actually, the OP had a pretty good approach of setting the week to a standard day of the week.  Wait... maybe it won't.  I hate date caluculations...